# Can an octave matrix hold strings and numbers together?

Tags: octave

Is there a way that an Octave Matrix would hold Strings and numbers together?

I want to have a matrix of the fallowing type:

```
A=["A","B","C","D";1,2,3,4;2,3,4,5;3,4,5,6;4,5,6,7];
```

So that the matrix will look like:

```
 A B C D
 1 2 3 4
 2 3 4 5
 3 4 5 6
 4 5 6 7
```

But when I try this I get:

```
ABCD
empty line
empty line
empty line
empty line
```

<sup>*`empty line` represents an empty line</sup>

And if I try to put strings that are more than 1 character in length, I get a number of columns mismatch error.

Is there a way to create a "mixed" octave matrix?

Comment: to answer your question, you have chars for digits as well `A = ["ABCD"; "1234"]`. But as it's been suggested, you're probably looking for cell arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you may be looking for a [*cell array*](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).